# SSO (Single sign on ) in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

has anyone implemented signgle sign on in MVC? Can anyone give me any example for single sign on in MVC.

Comment: That's quite a broad topic, and depends on what you mean by *SSO*. What's supported by your environment? NTLM? Kerberos? Claims? What's your current authentication strategy?

Answer (score 8):

I've implemented a SSO solution between multiple ASP.NET MVC applications hosted on the same parent domain (app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com, ...) by using Forms Authentication and setting the [domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) property of the cookie in web.config of all applications:

```
<forms 
   name="ssoauth" 
   loginUrl="/login" 
   protection="All"
   timeout="120"
   requireSSL="true"
   slidingExpiration="false">
   domain="domain.com" 
/>
```

When you set the domain property of the cookie, this cookie will automatically be sent by the client browser to all applications hosted on this domain and will be able to authenticated the user automatically.

If you want to implement a cross domain SSO using Forms Authentication here's what you could do:

1. The user navigates to `foo.com` and signs in. The application hosted on `foo.com` uses standard Forms Authentication, nothing fancy.
2. The user decides to go to `bar.com` and clicks on a link that you created. This link could contain a token parameter which will contain the encrypted username. This [encryption could be done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx) using the machine keys and look something like this: `https://bar.com?token=ABC`.
3. The application hosted on `bar.com` receives the request and because it uses the [**same machine keys**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) as the other application it is capable of [decrypting the token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.decrypt.aspx) and fetching the username. Then it simply signs in the user by emitting an authentication cookie locally and the user is automatically signed in `bar.com`.

Comment: do you have a code example for sso for cross domain applications?

Comment: @float, no I don't have code that I could share on the public domain due to copyright reasons. But the process is simple. The two domains just need to agree on a common secret password in order to be able to encrypt/decrypt the token.

Comment: I think this logic should be implemented in the global.asax in the method Application_AuthenticateRequest or? How can i access the url parameter in this method?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example for SSO for websites sharing same domain
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer here. Basically you need to set Authentication mode to windows on web.config and use HttpContext class to retrieve user identity which takes data from Active directory

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938106/950944