# Single sign on - Django to a java servlet

Tags: java, django, oauth, single-sign-on

I have a django front end which the client will log into. media streams selectable from the django ui will be served from a wowza server. The wowza server needs to know that the user has permission to view the media resource.

Wowza supports java packages so  I can insert user authentication into my wowza app to control access to media resources.

I own/control both servers, so I can configure a secure connection between them.

I *think* i should be looking into something like Oauth to pass credentials, but I am not certain as I have never looked into how to pass user authentication between two web services before.

So I think my question is: Is Oauth the appropriate mechanism to use? and if so, whats the basic requirements in terms of the django package and Java pacakge to use?

Or, is a single sign solution like this one more appropriate [SSO (Single sign on ) in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998394/sso-single-sign-on-in-mvc)

Comment: What do you intend by "passing credentials"?  If you need to communicate the username and password, then OAuth is not the right thing for you.

Comment: I definitely don't want to pass user/pass info. I want the user to access a resource through the java servlet, but only if they have logged into the django frontend. So maybe the term credentials is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What do not try [RemoteUser backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/) to authenticate and use http info from REMOTE_USER variable?