# How SetAuthCookie works for two different site

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies

I would like know how `SetAuthCookie` works for different application on same server?

Currently I have two similar applications with different virtual directories.

How can I make it so that if I login to one of them then it doesn't ask me for login on the other application, and the same for logout?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if both applications are hosted on the same top level domain. You should specify this domain in your web.config of both applications:

```
<forms 
   name="name" 
   loginUrl="URL" 
   defaultUrl="URL"
   domain="example.com">
</forms>
```

This way the forms authentication cookie will be emitted with the `domain` property setup and the client will effectively send it between the 2 applications. Another pre-requisite is that both applications share the same machine keys so that an authentication cookie that was encrypted by the first application can be successfully decrypted by the second application. If both applications are hosted on the same server you could set those machine keys in machine.config, if not then you could set them in web.config of each application:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="C03B1AB0BC1ACCD18EA915CBD87373010AD0DEC430A69871,IsolateApps" validation="AES" validationKey="C0ED7C430148AD4BC6505085DA4FD0DD3EE2453B566FC4EA4C7B3C2DCAB2025A79C774370CA884DF909CE9A3D379E544B7890D0A1CEE164141D3A966999DC625,IsolateApps" />
</system.web>
```

I've also covered this in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5000895/29407).

Comment: I have append IsolateApps to my config.But its not working for me.I am not able to login now.Have you any idea for this?

Comment: Well, assuming you have followed all the steps this should work. I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even the post is old but there is an easy solution add "name" in the form tag in web.config, coz if you dont give a name to the cookie it will have a default one

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" name="client" />
</authentication>
```

for the other application put another name, it works perfectly with me. good luck