# MVC single sign on with SSL across both sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, single-sign-on

After checking other SO questions I have single sign on (SSO) working. There are two MVC 4 applications hosted on the same machine with the same domain (foo.example.com and bar.example.com).

Now I would like to get this working so both sites are under SSL for all of their traffic (without writing my own authentication handling as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998394/sso-single-sign-on-in-mvc)).

I have worked out how to create self signed certificates in IIS7 and tried using one certificate for both sites and also having a separate certificate for each site.

After trying various configurations I am starting to believe it is not possible. I understand that SSO works by passing the authentication cookie between the applications when the web.config has been set up correctly with matching machine keys.

If the two sites are under SSL does this premise break down because of the encryption inherit in SSL? If it is possible I haven't worked out how to set it up.

If it is possible how do I do it:

One SSL certificate for both sites?

Two different SSL certificates?

If it is possible how do I set up IIS?

Any experience with this situation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SSL has nothing to do with SSO (except that it encrypts user credentials during logon). You can have a single certificate for any number of sites if your only goal is to encrypt the traffic. However, in production you want 2 separate certificates for both of your names - foo.example.com and bar.example.com. Note, browsers will complain if they're self signed because their trust chain cannot be verified. So it's better to buy certificates from trusted authorities like VeriSign, Thawte, etc.

As for setting up IIS check these links: [one](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis), [two](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm).