# Single Sign-On web app

Tags: c#, active-directory, single-sign-on

I need to authenticate into a web app using Single Sign-On, through Active Directory. I want to get the userName doing: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`, and then, through LDAP, get the password from the AD, and log into the web app.
The problem is that `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` returns empty.

Here is my Web.Config:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/SignIn" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
```

Now, I'm using active directory as a way to authenticate, and it works fine. But I also need to make it Single Sign-On.
Thanks

Comment: You need to look into using `Authentication mode="Windows"`

Comment: If i do that, the iis returns Error HTTP 401.0 - Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate Windows authentication.

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Don't forget to install the Windows Authentication feature for IIS.

If you want to use mixed authentication (Forms & Windows at the same time) I recommend [OWIN-MixedAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth)

Comment: If i do that, i cant use <authentication mode="Forms" />.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpContext to retrieve the user identity. You must set authentication mode as "Windows Authentication"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938106/950944